# Correct notation for "slice" of Integers

Tags: notation

Say I want to have the set of all integers between any two given integers $a$ and $b$. For example, if I want the set of all integers between $-3$ and $7$ I would get:

$$ \{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\} $$

How would I go about writing this for any given $a,b$?

*Note*: If I wanted the real numbers between $a$ and $b$, I could use $[a,b]$, therefore since the Integers are a subset of the Reals, I could write $[a,b]\cap\mathbb Z$, but that just seems inelegant. Is there any other way?

Comment: I have seen $m..n$ and $[m..n]$. Not as standard as interval notation for reals.

Comment: I have seen that before! Thank you very much!

Comment: Generally you can use the common [(real) interval notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29) if it is clear from the context that it denotes a subset of $\,\Bbb Z,\,$ e.g. $\ a\ {\rm mod}\ n \in [0,n) \ $

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat common notation is $[[a,b]]$. However, I  consider it as sufficiently non-standard to recommend defining it before  using it.

Comment: Common?  I don't recall *ever* seeing that used. Where did you see that?

Comment: If you read French, see the respective [Wikipedia page on Intervals](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervalle_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29) (at the end).

Comment: Maybe it is unique to some French authors. Have you ever seen it it English (or any other language?)

Comment: Quite possibly there are regional/cultural differences. Still I think it qualifies as "somewhat common." Just like $]a,b[$ is a somewhat common notation for an open interval. If you do not insist I would prefer to save the effort of providing all kinds of examples.

Comment: This notation is not mentioned in the corresponding [English Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Integer_intervals). But, of course, Wikipedia is far from an authority on such matters. Perhaps (native) readers of other languages will chime in.