# Notation for discrete intervals

Tags: notation

The well-known notation for continuous intervals is $[a,b]$. But what's the case for discrete intervals? Actually they are sets of finite elements $\left\{a, a+1, ..., b-1, b\right\}$ or infinite elements $\left\{0, 1, 2, ...\right\}$.

Is there any special notation or common practice for discrete intervals?

Comment: Isn't $[a,b] \cap \mathbb Z$ enough?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188685/correct-notation-for-slice-of-integers for the earlier version that I found by now. I cannot vote as dupe, and will vtc the other one.

Comment: I have seen $\mathbf{Z}_{a,b}$, but that might be very uncommon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A notation that is sometimes used is double-brackets, so $[[a,b]]$. (But it should still be explained what is meant.)

If one uses *only* the discrete version it is not uncommon to just use the usual notation $[a,b]$ for the discrete version, and to say so clearly somewhere.

Let me add that on [an earlier question regarding this subject](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188685/correct-notation-for-slice-of-integers) the notations $a..b$  and $[a..b]$ were also mentioned.

Comment: I believe to have answered this already but could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

In the book *Statistics for Business and Economics* by David R. Anderson,

Discrete intervals are simplified using ellipses. For instance:

B = 0, 1, 2, …, 20

E = 0, 1, 2, …, 50

V = 0, 1, 2, …, ∞

Unlike continuous intervals, which can be described using parentheses and square bracket, or inequality symbols, Like:

H = [0,8]   or   0 ≤ H ≤ 8

K = (0, ∞)   or   K > 0